# Ошибка invalid syntax хотя вроде все верно

Tags: python

Ошибка invalid syntax хотя вроде все верно.
Не могу понять в чем ошибка вроде верно написано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в 43 строке скобку закройте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На 43-ей строке вы забыли закрыть скобку.